# Removing the trailing slash from a URL with nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like the following URLs on my site to be equivalent:

```
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/
/foo/bar/index.html
```

and further I would like the second two forms to issue HTTP 301 redirects to the first form. I am just serving static pages, and they are arranged according to the third form. (In other words, when a user requests `/foo/bar` they should receive the file at `/usr/share/.../foo/bar/index.html`).

My `nginx.conf` currently contains the following:

```
rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 permanent;
index index.html;
try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
```

This works for requests for `/foo/bar/index.html`, but when I request `/foo/bar` or `/foo/bar/` Safari tells me that “too many redirects occurred”—I assume there’s an infinite redirect loop or something like that. How can I get nginx to map URLs to files in the way I’ve described?

### Edit: My full configuration

Here is my entire `nginx.conf` with my domain name replaced with “example.com”.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  server_tokens off;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss application/atom+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml;

  server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    server_name example.com 123.45.67.89 localhost;
    listen 80 default_server;

    # Redirect /foobar/ to /foobar
    rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 permanent;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/example.com;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do these files actually exist on the filesystem?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. Requests for `/foo/bar/index.html` should return the file at `/usr/share/nginx/www/foo/bar/index.html` or however it’s set up. All of the paths on the website correspond directly to filesystem paths.

Comment: @bdesham I can't reproduce. Here what I get with your config http://paste.ubuntu.com/7501697/

Comment: @AlexeyTen It’s odd that you’re getting something different. Thanks for looking into it. I’ve posted a configuration that ended up working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get my desired behavior by using this as the final `server` block in my configuration:

```
server {
  server_name example.com 123.45.67.89 localhost;
  listen 80 default_server;

  # Redirect /foobar/ and /foobar/index.html to /foobar
  rewrite ^(.+)/+$ $1 permanent;
  rewrite ^(.+)/index.html$ $1 permanent;

  root /usr/share/nginx/www/example.com;
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me - the `/index.html` URL is answered with HTTP 200 instead of a redirect; the "rewrite" lines are ignored. Is this still current?

Comment: @ChristophBurschka I think the issue is the line `rewrite ^(.+)/index.html$ $1`. If you change the `.+` to `.*`, I’m guessing that requests for `/index.html` will start being processed.

Answer (score 31):

Having this regex on your `server` block:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

would redirect all trailing slash URL's to the respective non trailing slash.

Comment: This addresses only part of the question.

Comment: This addresses the full title of the question.

Comment: Alternatively, `rewrite  ^(.+)/$  $1  permanent`.

Comment: Alternatively: `rewrite ^/(.*)/+$ /$1 permanent;`
`

Answer (score 19):

Never use rewrite:

```
  location ~ (?<no_slash>.*)/$ {
       return 301 $scheme://$host$no_slash;
  }
```

Comment: Can you expand on why you don’t think rewrite is a good idea?

Comment: Read nginx guide: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Comment: The reason your links suggests avoiding rewrites is for impoved legibility, not because they can cause unintended side effects. Your answer is far less readable than `rewrite ^(.+)/+$ $1 permanent;`

Comment: This is a good answer, I don't know why it's downvoted. [The article](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites) has a heading "Taxing Rewrites" that explains why `rewrite` can be bad. That's being said, the provided answer does also capture and match the URI, I'm not sure if will improve performance, it needs testing. Use this regex `(?<no_slash>.+)/$` instead to not redirect the home page.

Comment: Used `.+` to ensure alteast 1 char match to avoid infinite redirects when accessing root `/` path.

Comment: Alternatively, `location ~ ^(.+)/$ { return  301  $1$is_args$args; }`.

Comment: JFI: I tried `(?<no_slash>.+)/$`, `(?<no_slash>.*)/$`, and `^(.+)/$`. But all of them drops the port number when you are testing it in local env in docker. Or at least this is what I experienced

Answer (score 2):

```
    location ~ ^(.+)/$ {
      return 301 $scheme://$host$1;
    }
```

Used this to host sites from Next.js (v9&v10) static site generations where `host/url` works while `host/url/` triggers an Nginx 404.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($request_uri ~ (.*?\/)(\/+)$ ) {
return 301 $scheme://$host$1;
}
```

This rule will take care of any number of trailing slashes and will retain URL. It will also take care of base URL trailing slashes

Answer (score 0):

```
#removing trailing slashes at the end of url
if ($request_uri ~ (.*?)(\/+)$ ) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$1;
}
```

This rule will remove(redirect tot non-slashed url) any number of trailing slashes in the end of url.

Answer (score 0):

**After careful docs reading**, consulting with ChatGPT **and evaluating them**, reading some Q&As in Stackoverflow. Here is my final solution. I'll update this answer if I come across any new insight or improvements.

## Why

1. I have a dockerized app
2. I am using same dockerfile for deployment
3. Our QA uses same dockerfile to have the app up and running to perform manual testing and or e2e

## What should we do now?

Add this to your NGINX config file:

```
location ~ ^(.+)/$ { return 301 $scheme://$http_host$1; }
```

### JFI

1. I used `$http_host`* instead of `$host`. Why? Briefly touching the ocean: `$http_host` is always the value of the `Host` header field in the request header. [READ MORE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15414810/8784518).
2. `$host` was redirecting my app in local env from `http://localhost:3000/` to `http://localhost`. Not desirable at all.
3. Did not face any issue in the server (deployed version of app), not yet at least .
4. [Did not use any if clause since it is not appreciated by NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), besides that fact our location block gonna redirect soly when URL has a trailing slash :) and the rest of the times you could say it is idle .

*BTW I also did not find a case that `HOST` header was not sent to NGINX so I guess it is safe. But if you know any exception please comment it or edit this answer. I would be more than happy to address any improvement .

Comment: Chatgpt can give incorrect answers